# Dial address from same port that is being listened to

Tags: sockets, networking, go, client-server, p2p

I'm developing a P2P application and would like the nodes to serve as both clients and servers. For example, say that I establish a listening node with the following code running in a goroutine:

```
ln, _ := net.Listen("tcp", ":8080")
for { 
    conn, err := ln.Accept() 
    ..... 
}
```

Then, in another goroutine the logic has determined that it must contact another node to let it know of its existence, say on the localhost address ":8081" which also has a similar listening loop running.

If I just use `net.Dial("tcp", ":8081")`, it will choose a random port number to connect from, and the node on `8081` will try to contact that port instead of the correct one on `8080`. Is there a way to initiate the `net.Dial` call from `8080`? Is such a thing even allowed, or would the listener get confused and intercept the communications that were meant for the socket returned by `net.Dial`?

Comment: So, when a peer connects to you, you try to connect back on that socket's remote port?   You do realize that sockets are bi-directional, right?   Or is there some more complex thing going on that requires each node to have two connections between them?

Comment: Why is it important what port you dial out from?

Comment: When a new node boots up, it has a list of addresses that it needs to ping. You must first ping those nodes before they contact you back

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to control the local port when dialing out, you can use [net.DialTCP](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#DialTCP)

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work when using the same port as the listener. You get error: `bind: address already in use`